# Python Request inside Django View stop request when client gets disconnected

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have an DRF API in which a client will call then once called it will pass the data from client to another server (using request package) and returns to client the response of the other server.
In short, I am an API in the middle to sync them. Now, I need to terminate the request to other server (the one that is using request package) from my DRF API once the client got disconnected (by request timeout or explicitly terminated API call) to my DRF API.

Note. I need to terminate it because the data sending from the client is need to be map by the id being returned from the other server, and the client needs to save the id they received. In case your wondering why my API exist, the client can just sent the request over to the other server directly. Because the other server is a legacy server and it runs SOAP so my API is converting the JSON payloads to SOAP payload then from SOAP payload to JSON payload.

Comment: `once the client got disconnected to my DRF API.` -- How will this happen?

Comment: For example script timed out or they explicitly terminated the API call